# Is there Microsoft Synchronization Framework client in objective c and Java for Android?

Tags: android, ios, objective-c, microsoft-sync-framework

I am looking for a client implementation or library of the [Microsoft Synchronization Framework 2.1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb902854.aspx) for Objective-c and Java (for Android).

Can someone share some information on how to achieve this integration?   Is it a manual integration, or are there any libraries that are available that already implement the Sync Framework protocol on these mobile platforms.

I basically want to leverage the Sync Framework from a mobile app.